# how to store raw json string in cookie with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to store a json string in a cookie, however, the special characters, such as; `{"":""}` get encoded.

I have tried `setrawcookie()`, but it doesn't store more than one property-value.

```
$array = array('test' => 'value', 'anothertest' => 'not stored');

setrawcookie($this->cookie_customs_name, stripslashes(json_encode($array)), 
    strtotime($this->cookie_life_time), $this->cookie_path, $this->cookie_domain);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, is it possible to achieve this using the `setcookie()` method?

Comment: So, what's the problem?  What's wrong with the characters being encoded?  Can't you just decode it when you need to read it?

Comment: You should remove your stripslashes() call when setting. You need to escape those characters. Just remove them when retrieving the cookie.

Comment: stripslashes() on json can corrupt the json string. DON'T do that.

Answer (score 7):

The special characters should be escaped automatically when you use `setcookie()`. You should just need to remove the slashes once you retrieve the cookie.

```
$array = array(....);

setcookie($this->cookie_customs_name, json_encode($array), ...);
```

When retrieving the cookie:

```
$cookie = stripslashes($_COOKIE[$this->cookie_customs_name]);
$cookie = json_decode($cookie);
```

Untested, but should be all that is needed.